# Access IML via IPMI

Tags: hp, zabbix, ipmi

I am trying to get access to the Integrated Management Log (IML) via IPMI (iLO). Is it possible to obtain the IML via IPMI?

I have no issue with getting metrics from the built-in IPMI/iLO sensors, it's just I can't find a way of obtaining the IML via IPMI.

Answer (score 1):

See the [following notes](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0113790) from HP:

```
ipmiutil sel -N [Host IP Address] -U [User name] -P [Password]
```

---

Granted, I think it's better to use HP's purpose built tools where possible.

So `hpasmcli -s "SHOW IML"` from the host is another approach.

Or maybe some craziness using [Python-hpilo](https://pythonhosted.org/python-hpilo/#quick-usage-examples)...